# OPenQuery(SET FTMONLY OFF) issue with SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, openquery

This `OpenQuery` has always worked with SQL Server 2008. Now that we switched to SQL Server 2012, I am getting the error shown below.

Please help me fix this. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY(LEM,'SET FMTONLY OFF; set NOCOUNT ON; EXEC LeprinoCIPReporting.dbo.S_SA_CspTitrationSetUp @TitrationCnt = 33,@SkidKey = ''CIP10'',@ChemicalTypeKey = ''Sanitizer'',@EUKey = ''ppm'',@Enable = 1,@TitrationRangeHigh = 40,@TitrationRangeLow = 25,@OriginalTitrationSetupKey = 98,@Action = ''ins''')
```

Error

> Msg 11524, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1
>   The metadata could not be determined because statement 'Exec S_SA_CspTitrationSetupValidate' in procedure 'T_UpdateTitration' causes indirect recursion.

Comment: `SET FMTONLY` is deprecated; considering you don't want the header row, you don't need it in your query. The error, however, implies that you're causing a recursion loop (so, an SP is calling another SP, which is calling the original SP, or similar). Is that the case?

Comment: Using openquery I am calling a storedprocedure that has select statements and I am also using table variables inside the stored procedure I am calling. I removed the "SET FMTONLY OFF;" and I still get the same error.

Comment: Metadata determination has changed with SQL Server 2012; unfortunately, some edge cases are affected by this where earlier versions could muddle through, but 2012 will give up and complain. If your stored procedure actually returns a fixed result set, use `WITH RESULT SETS` to tell SQL Server about the metadata without the need for discovery. If your stored procedure returns a dynamic result set, try to figure out a way to simplify the indirect recursive calls, for example by calling different stored procedures based on the input values.

Comment: Unfortunately, my stored procedure returns different result sets.

Comment: Then I'm afraid it's a case of "adapt or perish". AFAIK there's no way to make SQL Server 2012 go back to the way things were in 2008; things like DB compat levels have no influence on this.